# Redshift window function for change in column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands

I have a redshift table with amongst other things an `id` and `plan_type` column and would like a window function group clause where the `plan_type` changes so that if this is the data for example:

```
| user_id | plan_type | created    |
|---------|-----------|------------|
| 1       | A         | 2019-01-01 |
| 1       | A         | 2019-01-02 |
| 1       | B         | 2019-01-05 |
| 2       | A         | 2019-01-01 |
| 2       | A         | 2-10-01-05 |
```

I would like a result like this where I get the first date that the `plan_type` was "new":

```
| user_id | plan_type | created    |
|---------|-----------|------------|
| 1       | A         | 2019-01-01 |
| 1       | B         | 2019-01-05 |
| 2       | A         | 2019-01-01 |
```

Is this possible with window functions?

## EDIT

Since I have some garbage in the data where `plan_type` can sometimes be null and the accepted solution does not include the first row (since I can't have the `OR is not null` I had to make some modifications. Hopefully his will help other people if they have similar issues. The final query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 
    user_id, 
    plan_type, 
    created_at,
    lag(plan_type) OVER (PARTITION by user_id ORDER BY created_at) as prev_plan,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION by user_id ORDER BY created_at) as rownum 
 FROM tablename
 WHERE plan_type IS NOT NULL
) userHistory 
WHERE
    userHistory.plan_type <> userHistory.prev_plan
    OR userHistory.rownum = 1
ORDER BY created_at;
```

The `plan_type IS NOT NULL` filters out bad data at the source table and the outer where clause gets any changes OR the first row of data that would not be included otherwise.

ALSO BE CAREFUL about the created_at timestamp if you are working of your `prev_plan` field since it would of course give you the time of the new value!!!

Comment: Is the last date an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I think `lag()` is the simplest approach:

```
select user_id, plan_type, created
from (select t.*,
             lag(plan_type) over (partition by user_id order by created) as prev_plan_type
      from t
     ) t
where prev_plan_type is null or prev_plan_type <> plan_type;
```

This assumes that plan types can move back to another value and you want each one.

If not, just use aggregation:

```
select user_id, plan_type, min(created)
from t
group by user_id, plan_type;
```

Comment: thanks this is great. However since I have some garbage in the data where the value sometimes is null in the meantime I had to modify the WHERE conditions a bit but your solution overall is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use   `row_number()` window function

```
 select * from
    (select *,row_number()over(partition by user_id,plan_type order by created) rn
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `lag()`

```
select * from
(
select user_id, plant_type, lag(plan_type) over (partition by user_id order by created) as changes, created
from tablename
)A where plan_type<>changes and changes is not null
```